# Azure Pipeline Task inputs won't accept variables

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

In the azure pipeline yaml files, the variable `imgRepoName` is trimmed from the `gitRepoName`. An bash echo for `gitRepoName` shown `core/cqb-api`; bash echo for `imgRepoName` shown `cqb-api`

```
variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-18.04'
  gitRepoName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
  imgRepoName: $(basename $(gitRepoName))

  - job: build_push_image
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build and Push image
        inputs:
          repository: imgRepoName
          command: buildAndPush
          containerRegistry: "coreContainerRegistry"
          tags: test2
```

Issues:

When I wrote `repository: "cqb-api"` as the input for the docker task it works just fine, while use the variable directly as shown above won't create any images in the container registry.

PS, I also tried `repository: $(imgRepoName)` it give out the following error

```
invalid argument "***/$(basenamecore/cqb-api):test2" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that it is executed at runtime. So `gitreponame` is replaced but basename function is not recognized in this context. You can check this:

```
variables:
  gitRepoName: $(Build.Repository.Name)

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        $name = $(basename $(gitRepoName))
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=imgRepoName]$name"

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and Push
  inputs:
    repository: $(imgRepoName)
    command: build
    Dockerfile: docker-multiple-apps/Dockerfile
    tags: |
      build-on-agent
```

It works for me.